# invite friends function of hackbook for iphone doen't work on my iphone4s

Tags: facebook, apprequests

i downloaded hackbook from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook (* i am not sure this is the right place to download it), because i wanted to know how to send an invitation to a friend from a iphone native application.

i clicked "send invite", then on the pop-up page, I selected a friend(another facebook account of mine) and pushed "send" button.
"Sent request successfully." is displayed on the bottom of the screen.

but I don't get any request.

who can tell me how to send an invitation, better if there is a sample.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your application is in sandbox mode. Users who are not listed as developers/testers will not receive invites to applications that they do not have the permissions to view.

---

**UPDATE:**
As the OP has discovered (see comments below) - the problem was to do with not having a `Canvas URL` set up in the application settings.

Im not 100% sure why this is ( being an iPhone native application ).  Reading through the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests) ( once again :S ) revealed no stated requirement of the `Canvas URL`.  My best guess is that the request needs to be able to be redirected somewhere after it is accepted, if you dont specify the `canvas URL` maybe somehow you invalidate the request.
Did all the requests that did not go out appear once you specified the `Canvas URL`?

Comment: thank you. I'll try. by the way, i added an invalid canvas url, and now request can be received though an errer happened when checking its contents.

Comment: i changed it to sandbox mode, and added a developer. still not work as long as there is no canvas url. i don't understand why canvas url is necessary since my app is an iphone navtive one

Comment: thank you for your reply. requests sent before the setting of canvas url disappears.does it mean i have to create a web page just for it?

Comment: it seems so...  the request has to send you somewhere once you respond to it